# Lemoon - Select Form Template not available

Tags: forms, content-management-system, lemoon

I have started using Lemoon CMS for a new site, everything is working great with one exception.... Forms.  Each time I try to create a New Form i am given the option to Select a Form Template.... however this dropdown is not populated with anything.  There is a FormTemplate.aspx file which looks intact, and when I try to view my new page/form I get the message **Form "" not found.**

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use forms you need to first create/design a form. You do this under the manage/content types section (/admin/manage/content/default.aspx). There you need to click the "Design form template" link. You can now create your form. Once it is saved you need to create a page in your site that will hold the form. Select your newly created form in the "Select form" dropdown and click Publish.

Comment: Awesome, I missed the small options on that page to actually ADD the form elements and such. Thank you!